# SQL Server : dynamic port forwarding

Tags: sql-server, tcp, portforwarding

I need to get access from the outside of the network to internal SQL Server (configured connection via dynamic ports).

Is it possible to get to it from the outside, or it has to be changed to a non-dynamic port configuration?

If yes, the range of ports have to be forwarded? How does it work?

Best Regards,
Val

Answer (score 0):

You need to portforward the following ports in your router:

8990 (TCP and UDP)

8991 (TCP and UDP)

8992 (TCP and UDP)

3050 (TCP and UDP)

1024 (TCP and UDP)

1433 (TCP and UDP)

443 (TCP and UDP)

Here is a guide how to portforward in your router: https://portforward.com/router.htm

Source: https://www.currentware.com/support/configure-port-forwarding-for-remote-workers-sql/

Comment: What about the dynamic port SQL Server is listening on? I suggest a VPN connection instead of opening up the database server to the public internet.